# laravel4.1 can't render template when upload to server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

it's weird, when developing localhost, everything works fine, the default page shows.

after upload to server, it just show blank page !

it's driving me crazy !

```
echo 'outside route';
Route::get('/', function()
{
    echo 'inside route';
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

both `echo` works, but `View::make('hello')` just don't work, `views/hello.php` is the default  file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to fix your permissions on the remote server, as it might be a cache issue.

1) Run recursive chmod on you storage path (*assuming you already have proper file ownage)

```
cd /path/to/laravel
chmod -R 755 app/storage
```

2) Clear cache with Artisan

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

3) Refresh page, should work now.

*if you are running the http server as different user (for example you're on Ubuntu and Apache runs as user www-data), you might want to set file ownage for Laravel app files as well

```
chown -R www-data .
```

## EDIT:

Just a remark about your code example - remember that if you want to use Blade templating engine you have to name your files accordingly. If you want to have a blade template called 'something', you will place your code in `app/views/something.blade.php` and than reffer to it for example `View::make('something')`.